# Executing tcl script inside php

Tags: php, tcl, passthru

I am trying to execute tcl script inside php using passthru function. TCL script perfectly executes on the normal unix terminal. Whereas in php its not giving expected results on the browser.

I am passing the environment variable using passthru function in php. The environment variable is getting passed correctly but I am noticing the rest of the commands are not giving out the result. So I experimented trying to execute ls command and date command.

`date` command gives the output on the browser whereas `ls` doesn't give any output on the browser.

Why is this happening? It's the same result with `who` and other commands with large output. Is there anything I am missing here??

Here is my sample tcl script ls_sample.tcl

```
puts "entering tcl"
set date_variable [exec date]
puts $date_variable
set ls_variable [exec ls]
puts $ls_variable
```

Sample output on the browser:

```
executing tclscript entering tcl Thu Oct 18 23:23:38 PDT 2012
```

why is `ls` not printed?  Whereas it works completely fine on the unix terminal?

Comment: That's curious. Does even `exec /bin/ls -la` not produce any output? (Just trying to exclude the possibility that you're executing in an empty directory…)

Comment: If you are using tcl -- why exec date and ls? You have clock and glob commands to avoid executing yet another subprocess.

Comment: @patthoyts I'm presuming that they're proxies for something else (that is probably proprietary).

Comment: @patthoyts: I was just experimenting with these commands. My actual script is something different but the issue is the same.

Answer (score 1):

I think it could be an Apache/Php/your system configuration problem. I just tried the same example under my machine and got the right result:

```
entering tcl Sat Oct 27 11:08:03 CEST 2012 blog forum index.rvt launchtcl.php pttest.tcl sd test.tcl test2.tcl
```

I also tried to reproduce the problem by doing these things, but it always worked for me:

- `ls /usr/bin`, for getting a longer string
- `who`, for variety
- `chown`ed the `.tcl` file to a different user/group from the one used by Apache (`www-data:www-data`)
- `chown`ed the `.tcl` file (as before), and `chmod o-rx` the directory
- switched from `passthru('tclsh pttest.tcl')` to `passthru('./pttest.tcl')`, made `pttest.tcl` executable and added `#!/usr/bin/tclsh` as first line
- the same as before, but `chown`ing the `pttest.tcl` file

None of these tests gave me your problem. I'm now adding the Apache configuration for the testing directory I used.

```
<Directory />
    Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm index.tcl index.rvt
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

Sorry if I can't answer your question, but maybe these information can help you.

Comment: Other possibility is to exec using `shell_exec` and (or) redirecting stderr adding ` 2>&1` to the command, and check the results. They might contain some useful information, such as 'tcl is not in the PATH' or something like that.